# How do I migrate Ant build to Maven Resolver Ant Tasks using Groovy

Tags: maven, groovy, build, ant

Currently task to migrate our build process to gradle using [maven resolver ant tasks](https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/). I've gone through the docs extensively, but I can't manage to get it to work. What I'm trying to accomplish is, having it read the dependencies from the `pom.xml` and install from our remote repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve my issue by just switching over to gradle using ant task.